# Plotting data from several files on one plot

Tags: dataset, ggplot2, scatterplot

I have more than one file of data from different experiments. For the sake of the argument here, let's say I have three files `E1.txt`, `E2.txt`, `E3.txt`.

I anticipate that I will have more files in future, say `E4.txt`, `E5.txt`, etc.

Each of these files has two columns, Time(h) and Growth. Plotting data from one file, for instance, E1.txt, is simple. I just read the data from `E1.txt` using the `read.table` function in R. I then assign the data from `E1.txt` to variable `E1`.

Then I just use the plot function this way, `plot(E1)`.

Now, what do I need to write in a script that will plot all the data from the `E1.txt`, `E2.txt`, and `E3.txt` files on the same plot?

I thought of writing `plot(c(E1,E2,E3))`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to use [`points`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/points.html):

```
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, len = 51)
y1 = sin(x)
y2 = cos(x)
plot(x, y1)
points(x, y2, col = "red")
```

[image]

If your data files share a common axis, you can use [`matplot`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/matplot.html):

```
a <- matrix (rnorm(20), c(5,1))
matplot(a, type = "b")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `[FileName]$[VariableName]` to refer to different variables in different datasets:

```
set.seed(276)

# Simulate data:

E1 <- data.frame(time=seq(1:365), growth=rnorm(365))
E2 <- data.frame(time=seq(1:365), growth=rnorm(365))

# Determine the right y-axis limits:

ymax <- max(c(E1$growth, E2$growth), na.rm=T)
ymin <- min(c(E1$growth, E2$growth), na.rm=T)

# Plot the first graph:

plot(E1$time, E1$growth, type="l", col="red", ylim=c(ymin, ymax),
     xlab="Time", ylab="Growth")

# Plot the second line onto the first graph:

points(E2$time, E2$growth, type="l", col="blue")
```

Result:

[image]